# Acceptance of Mahavakyas in Shankara's time

Tags: vedas, history, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, yajur-veda

The [Vakyas 2 & 4 of four MahaVakyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas) clearly identify the Self with Brahman... as a Vedic tradition.

Non-duality had always been a well established fact of Sanatana Dharma... right?

Then why did Sankaracharya in his days face so much resistance while  spreading the already well known Advaita concept? Is n't it an essentially Vedic concept?

Comment: Non-duality has been a **"well-interpreted"** (not "well-established") fact of the SanAtan Dharma, especially by the *Advaita* School. It's definitely not a "well-established" and the only fact. We have "Duality" thought Schools too, "Special-Duality", "Special-Non Special Non-Duality", and so on...

Comment: Thats because of deep Kaliyuga around 50BC (Deepest Kaliyuga was 2400 years after death of Krishna(3000BC) till birth of Buddha(500 BC)). Right now we are ascending age of Aquarius(ruled by Varuna) for 12000 years and its Dwapra-Treta junction. http://www.dwapara-yuga.org . Vishnu-Shiva are interpolated Puranic gods of Kaliyuga but there Vedic names are Varuna-Mitra. Varuna rules night and Mitra rules day. Just like we have 12 hours day(6am-6pm) and 12 hours night(6pm-6am). Uttarayan(Mar-Aug) and Dakishnayan(Sept-Feb),similarly 12000 ruled by Varun https://www.pujaabhishekam.com/archives/2855

Comment: And 12000 years are ruled by Mitra. Gautam Buddha was a form of Varuna/Vishnu, thats why next Buddha is Mitra/Shiva(at end of next Satyuga(around 12000 AD) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya .In Kaliyuga people identify with body,senses and cant understand their real Self i.e. Atman and hence fight with one another in name of Gods, caste, race,gender etc., in Satyuga everyone knows their real Self(hansas) is Atman and theirs only one varna of brahmgyanis and therefore Mitra(Friend) to everyone

Comment: @ Vivikta  Imo the most pioneering step was taken by Shankacharya , his guru and peers. It assumes new responsibility onto oneself for conduct of a dharmic way of life.  In times before that the devotee or any person had a fear of the superior unknown and worshipped God in servitude due to possible punishment by an external power through an as yet unknown mechanism. Modifications of Dwaita, Visishtadwaita are more academic/scholastic temporal developments into the modalities of acceptance of power transfer realized towards the self.

Comment: **Non-duality had always been a well established fact of Sanatana Dharma... right?** Sir, historically, before Shankara, there is no evidence to show that non-dualism was the dominant vedantic school. bhedAbheda might have been more mainstream before Shankara